# How to synchronize constant writing and periodically reading and updating

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

**Defining the problem:**

We have this IOT device which each send us logs about cars locations. We want to compute the distance the car is travelling online! so when ever a log comes(after putting it in a queue etc) we do this:

```
type Delta struct {
    DeviceId string
    time     int64
    Distance float64
}
var LastLogs = make(map[string]FullLog)
var Distances = make(map[string]Delta)


func addLastLog(l FullLog) {
    LastLogs[l.DeviceID] = l
}
func AddToLogPerDay(l FullLog) {
    //mutex.Lock()
    if val, ok := LastLogs[l.DeviceID]; ok {
        if distance, exist := Distances[l.DeviceID]; exist {
            x := computingDistance(val, l)
            Distances[l.DeviceID] = Delta{
                DeviceId: l.DeviceID,
                time:     distance.time + 1,
                Distance: distance.Distance + x,
            }
        } else {
            Distances[l.DeviceID] = Delta{
                DeviceId: l.DeviceID,
                time:     1,
                Distance: 0,
            }
        }
    }
    addLastLog(l)

}
```

which basically calculates distance using a utility function! so in `Distances` each device Id is mapped to some distance traveled! now here is where the problem starts: While this distances are added to `Distances map`, I want a go routine to put this data in the database but since there are many devices and many logs and so on doing this query for every log is not a good idea. So I need to this for every 5 second which means every 5 seconds try to empty the list of all last distances added to the map. I wrote this function:

```
func UpdateLogPerDayTable() {
    for {
        for _, distance := range Distances {
            logs := model.HourPerDay{}
            result := services.CarDBProvider.DB.Table(model.HourPerDay{}.TableName()).
                Where("created_at >?  AND device_id = ?", getCurrentData(), distance.DeviceId).
                Find(&logs)
            if result.Error != nil && !result.RecordNotFound() {
                log.Infof("Something went wrong while checking the log: %v", result.Error)
            } else {
                if !result.RecordNotFound() {
                    logs.CountDistance = distance.Distance

                    logs.CountSecond = distance.time

                    err := services.CarDBProvider.DB.Model(&logs).
                        Update(map[string]interface{}{
                            "count_second":   logs.CountSecond,
                            "count_distance": logs.CountDistance,
                        })
                    if err.Error != nil {
                        log.Infof("Something went wrong while updating the log: %v", err.Error)
                    }

                } else if result.RecordNotFound() {
                    dayLog := model.HourPerDay{
                        Model:         gorm.Model{},
                        DeviceId:      distance.DeviceId,
                        CountSecond:   int64(distance.time),
                        CountDistance: distance.Distance,
                    }
                    err := services.CarDBProvider.DB.Create(&dayLog)
                    if err.Error != nil {
                        log.Infof("Something went wrong while adding the log: %v", err.Error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    }
}
```

it is called `go utlis.UpdateLogPerDayTable()` on another go routine. However there are many problems here:

1. I don't know how to secure `Distances` so when I add it in another routine I read it somewhere else ,every thing is ok!(The problem is that I want to use go channels and don't have any idea how to do it)
2. How can I schedule tasks in go for this problem?
3. Probably I will add a redis to store all the devices that or online so I could do the select query faster and just update the actual database. also add an expire time for redis so if a device didn't send and data for some time, it vanishes! where should I put this code?

Sorry If my explanations weren't enough but I really need some help. specifically for code implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go has a really cool pattern using [for / select](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5) over multiple channels.  This allows you to batch distance writes using both a timeout and a max record size.  Using this pattern requires using channels.

First thing is to model your distances as a channel:

```
distances := make(chan Delta)
```

Then you an keep track of the current batch

```
var deltas []Delta
```

Then

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 5)

var deltas []Delta

for {
  select {
     case <-ticker.C:
        // 5 seconds up flush to db
        // reset deltas
     case d := <-distances:
        deltas = append(deltas, d)
        if len(deltas) >= maxDeltasPerFlush {
           // flush
           // reset deltas
        }
  }
}
```

---

> I don't know how to secure Distances so when I add it in another
>   routine I read it somewhere else ,every thing is ok!(The problem is
>   that I want to use go channels and don't have any idea how to do it)

If you intend to keep a map and share memory you need to protect it using [mutual exclusion (mutex)](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/9) to synchronize access between go routines.  Using a [channel](https://gobyexample.com/channels) allows you to send a copy to a channel, removing the need for synchronizing across the Delta Object.  Depending on your architecture you could also create a pipeline of go routines connected by channels, which could make it so only a single go routine ([monitor go routine](https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/golang-monitors-and-mutexes-a-light-survey-84f04f9b7c09)) is accessing the `Delta`, also removing the need for synchronization.

> How can I schedule tasks in go for this problem?

Using a channel as the primitive for how you pass `Deltas` to different go routines :)

> Probably I will add a redis to store all the devices that or online so
>   I could do the select query faster and just update the actual
>   database. also add an expire time for redis so if a device didn't send
>   and data for some time, it vanishes! where should I put this code?

This depends on your finished architecture.  You could write a [decorator](https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/designpatterns-considering-decorators-b4968a8006e8) for the select operation, which would check redis first then go to the DB.  The client of this function wouldn't have to know about this.  Write operations could be done the same way: Write to persistent store and then write back to redis with the cached value and the expiration.  Using decorators the client wouldn't need to know about this, they would just perform the Reads and Writes and the cache logic would be implemented inside of the decorators.  There are many ways for this, and its largely dependent on where your implementation settles.